# How to create a new MVC project with EF6 Db first approach in VS 2015

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first, new-project

I want to create a new MVC project with EF to use database first approach.

So I have created a new MVC 5.2.3 project in Visual Studio 2015 using a wizard which created default Account and Manage users models, controllers and views.

The connection string is the sort of

`Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MyProject-20161112112119.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MyProject-20161112112119;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient`

And I have a few issues here:

1. There is no mdf file within `App_Data` folder of my project so I have no idea where the hell the database went to.
2. I guess the app uses Code first approach by default so obviously I would like to change it. An idea is to just copy the tables from within the internal project db created on set up and add them to my new database I will use for db first approach. But I can't find the existing app database (see point 1).
3. I can connect to the server which is used in the connstring above (`(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB`) via Management Studio but it has no databases at all not even the one mentioned in the conn string. And the file is not present within `App_Data` folder
4. So I have created a brand new database `MyProjectDb` within my `localhost` server using Sql Server Management Studio with the intention to use it for db first approach.
5. I have created a new project `MyProject.Database` within my solution to use the newly created database `MyProjectDb`.
6. I checked and can see that the database string in `MyProject.Database` project properties has connstring datasource as `(LocalDb)/ProjectsV13` instead of `localhost`. The question is why such strange source rather than my `localhost`? And how to force new db project to create a database within `localhost` server?
7. Next I have modified the properties of the database project (Debug tab) to use in the connection string `localhost` as datasource and the new database `MyProjectDb` I created.
8. Now I right click on my database project `MyProject.Database`: add > new item > Table. I created the table.
9. I can now see the database in SQL Server Objects Explorer under `Projects-MyProject` folder as well as I can see the database `MyProjectDb` I created under my `localhost` server within SQL Server Management Studio. The former has the table I created, the later does not have it under Tables (I refreshed the tables of course). This is weird and I am confused whether they are actually the same databases or somehow VS copied the database instead of using the one I created?
10. I right click my web project in the Solution Explorer: add > new item > Data > ADO.NET Entity Data Model, I give the name, on the next screen I am selecting `EF Designer from database` option. I click next and get to the screen where I can create `New connection`. I am clicking this and the only server I can select from the list is `NICKO-PC` server. (Remember: the db project I created in VS defaulted to `(LocalDb)?ProjectsV13` server) If I try to insert `localhost` or anything else it does change back to `NICKO-PC` but I guess it is anyway the same as `localhost` server cos when I expand available databases my `MyProjectDb` database is on the list. So I select it and go next.
11. I get `Choose Your Database Objects And Settings` screen. And now I can't see my table I created using my `MyProject.Database` project. There is no table to choose to be more precise. So obviously I can't create any db entities to use in my application.

I am stuck.

I hope my description of events is not confusing.

Can anyone clever help me to do what I want please?

1. I don't know why the web project used db file on some strange `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB` server and database project creates it under `(LocalDb)/ProjectsV13` instead?
2. How can I create my own new database and use it for both web app and database project then create entities based on the db first approach?
3. How to get the tables and other object in data entity wizard I want to create model entities within my app?

This is basically what I need.

Please let me know how you create a project using Db First approach cos I'm not getting anywhere with VS studio wizards.

Thank you

*** EDIT ***

My DbContext class is rather simple and created by MVC project I installed together with user models:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

It points to the default conn string as you can see which I changed to connect to my newly created db `MyProjectDb`.

Comment: Have you done any tutorials for this?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Of course I looked for similar cases - found nothing but standard code first approach and empty MVC project while I'm using MVC project with pre-created user access models

Answer (score 1):

Once you actually run the site *and* hit something that requires database access. Entity Framework *should* create the database. I think you might have simply diverged off the path too soon.

Regardless, yes, the default will be code first, or perhaps more appropriately: the default will be to create an new database. The old "model first" and "database first" approaches have been deprecated, and while you can still use them *for now*, it's not recommended, especially when building a new app you'll need to support long term. That said, "code first", despite the name, can actually be used with an existing database or to create a new one. You'll just need to alter your context slightly to use an existing database:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("ConnectionStringName")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, edit your Web.config and add a connection string to the existing database you want to connect to. Ensure that the name you give it there, matches where "ConnectionStringName" is in the code above.

Comment: Hi, thanks but it doesn't explain what's happening. I installed default MVC app which already has `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`
    within `IndentityModels` class and it is set to the connection from the web.config. In Web. config I have changed the conn to point to my new database. But it's still messed up and neither my database project nor my web project does not see the new database. See my edit above